# Number of rows matched and changed not equal

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a simple update query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = replace(mycolumn, "somestring", "otherstring")
WHERE mycolumn LIKE '%somestring%';
```

Sample output:

```
Query OK, 198 rows affected (24.18 sec)
Rows matched: 200  Changed: 198  Warnings: 0
```

How it is possible that rows changed count is less than matched? Each matched row should cointain `somestring` in column, so it should be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29157) which was reported and is now reverted in MySQL 5.1 onwards.

From the same:

> Whether the number of rows updated is different from the number of
>   rows found is engine specific.  Some storage engines are able to read
>   just a subset of the columns when doing an update (InnoDB is one such
>   engine). So the server can't reliably check if a row will not be
>   updated. And because of that it will always have number of rows
>   updated equal to the number of rows found. The reason that this worked
>   differently in 5.0 is the fact that in 5.1 the server passes
>   information for the columns it needs to read to InnoDB and hence not
>   all the columns are read anymore. In 5.0 such information was not
>   passed down to the InnoDB storage engine, so it always returned all
>   the columns and a check wether a rows is updated was possible.